# Raspberry Pi motor hat not a 1 to 1 with stepper driver?

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, motor-controller, stepper-driver

Just a general question that someone hopefully can answer.

I've been working on getting a large stepper motor setup with a Raspberry Pi, so I went for a DM556T stepper driver.

I've gotten the smaller NEMA 17 steppers to work with the Raspberry Pi motor hat and NPM library seen [here](https://github.com/jcane86/motor-hat). If I try the same library, with the large stepper & stepper driver, it does not work. I have debugged enough to know that I can get the motor to move with just the GPIO pins (although not ideal, I am figuring out how to program it now) but I was wondering why the Raspberry Pi motor hat cannot drive the motor the same way it does a NEMA 17. I thought the stepper driver was meant to be a 1 to 1 with the motor hat. If it is a power issue somehow, wouldn't the stepper motor be unable to move through the GPIO pins directly?

Anyone willing to help or point me in the direction of how to operate a large stepper with a Raspberry Pi effectively with this motor-hat is appreciated. I've been really trying to understand why some stuff seems to just click together while other things need a lot of configuration.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: maybe you did not wire it correctly ... what is `large stepper motor`

Comment: It's wired correctly. I'm programming it now by hand but I was wondering if others have come across the same issue. A large stepper motor (aka something that requires a Stepper driver to power it) with a raspberry pi motor hat. I figured since a nema 17 stepper is like plug and play with the motor hat, so would a large stepper but it does not appear to do so and I do not know why.